# using Clipboard in WP7 programming

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically copy/paste in windows phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761798/how-to-programmatically-copy-paste-in-windows-phone)

how can i use clipboard in my Windows Phone 7 app?
i want to type a text in my app, then this text should be accessible in another apps.
please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question could have hardly been timed better.

I've just released a library which allows you to do just that. (Even without the "NoDo" update.)

Check it out at http://wp7clipboard.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanx matt. i have your library and i want to test it then i will publish my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with current SDK.

Latest SDK supports Copy & Paste but, I believe it does not provide programmatic access to Clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming "NoDo" update that includes support for copy and paste does not provide any programmatic access to the clipboard. Any `TextBox` control and textbox fields in a browser will automatically provide support for copy and paste, but this is completely outside of the user's control.